# Node.js: can't test inputs with Expect

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, try-catch

I'm trying to test errors with Expect, but inside this try/catch block the logs aren't working. And before this block, I can see that the array is being populated by the inputs...I don't understand why the script is not entering the try/catch block so the test can be made and the proper error message can be returned. Any help would be apreciated. The code:

```
inputs = ["fname", "surname"];

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var errors=[];
       errors.push(inputs[i]);
      console.log("FNAME"+inputs[0]+ "SURNAME" +inputs[1]); //works

         try {

            if (inputs[i] == 0) {
                expect(inputs[i]).to.be.NaN;
                expect(inputs[i]).to.have.length.above(1);
                console.log("FNAME FIELD IS " + inputs[0]); //NOT WORKING
            }

           if (inputs[i] == 1) {
                expect(inputs[i]).to.be.NaN;
                expect(inputs[i]).to.have.length.above(1);
                console.log("SURNAME FIELD IS " + inputs[1]); //not working
            }            

            return "OK";

        } catch (errors) {
            console.log("STACK" + errors(inputs[0]));
           //save(errors);
            return errors;

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code work as expected.

It just never reach the condition `inputs[i] == 0` nor `inputs[i] == 1`, so it return `'OK'` like it should, and do not catch any error because there is no error to catch.

```
var inputs = ["fname", "surname"]
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  console.log(inputs[i] == 0)  // false
  console.log(inputs[i] == 1)  // false
}
```

Also you should definitly change the `catch` part, because in case of exception there will be an error as variable `errors` is not a function.